# Simple explanation of the maximum work theorem

Tags: thermodynamics

I have been trying to understand the maximum-work theorem for some time. But it seems like an impossible task, and it is a very confusing concept. First, the sign convention of work is different in different resources. Further, phrases like "work is maximum" and "delivery of work" do not specify if it is work done *on* the system or *by* the system. Is there a way to explain the maximum work theorem in simple terms. What is the physical basis for the maximum-work theorem and what are the implication.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to understand the maximum-work theorem is through an example. Consider compression of a gas. First we are going to compress the gas reversible keeping $P_{\text{ext}}=P_{\text{int}}$, and then compare it with an irreversible compression where $P_{\text{ext}}>P_{\text{int}}$. Points to note before the explanation are:

1. Work done is given by the area under a $P$-$V$ graph.
2. Compression work is positive.
3. During compression, work is done *on* the gas.

#### Reversible Compression

[image: work done during reversible compression]

The work done is given by area $A$.

#### Comparison with Irreversible Compression

[image: work done during irreversible compression]

The work done is given by area $A+B$.

---

**Conclusion:** It can be seen that $A+B > A$. Thus, work done *on* a system is maximum, and, as a corollary, work done *on* a system is minimum during a reversible process, respectively.

Comment: Yes, but if the external pressure is greater than that of the system, what is being pushed against? Shouldn't the work be $-p_{system}\Delta V$?

Comment: @BuckThorn the definition of work is $-P_{ext}\Delta V$.

Comment: That's *the definition*, but I'm wondering why that is the definition. After all, when $p<p_{ext}$ only part of the external pressure is overcoming the internal pressure, or? Take the extreme case of pushing into a vacuum. Is any work done?

Comment: In Europe, the work is positive when entering a gaseous system, For example in a compression, w > 0, and the volume decreases : Delta V < 0. So w = -p·Delta V. As a consequence, the change of internal enegrgy is DeltaU = Q + w = Q  - p·Delta V. On the contrary, USA scientists think mechanically that adding heat to a gaseous system must produce some work, as the gas volume increases by heating, DeltaV > 0. So : w = + p·Delta V, and the change of internal energy is : DeltaU  = Q- w = Q - p DeltaV. As a whole, Delta U is the same everywhere, but w is positive in USA, and negative in Europe.

Comment: @Maurice AFAIK it is not regional. Each of conventions was originated in different activity domains. For long time, physics and engineering used dominantly Q - W convention, while chemistry used mostly Q + W  convention. Later physics gradually shifted to mostly Q + W convention, engineering is possibly more conservative.

Comment: @Poutnik. Thank you for the complement of information.